# To match a range of values and the result should indicate with change of background color

Tags: excel

I want to match a range of data in one sheet with range of data in another sheet in excel and the result should indicate in change of background color.

In a worksheet i am having two sheets, I want to compare a "L" tab in sheet 1 with "B" tab in sheet 2.

The matched items in the sheet 1 should change to some background color.

Comment: Firstly, give an real example, write your attempt, then ask help

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Is it understandable now?

Comment: Just use `VLOOKUP()`. However, this formula doesnt highlight, but it helps to compare. `=VLOOKUP(L1,'Sheet 2'!B:B,1,FALSE') Put it into cell `C1`

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Use HLOOKUP or VLOOKUP with IFERROR to find match cell
- Step 2: Use Conditional Formatting to highlight match cell